# Go to view by clicking on th

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have view with table

Here is some code

```
 <tr style="background: #d1d3d4">
    <th></th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyName)
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vacancies.FirstOrDefault().VacancyName)
    </th>
```

I need to go to another view , by clicking  on `<th>` text. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an HTML anchor tag (`<a>`). In .NET MVC you can use the `@Url.Action()` helper to create your link to your controller action.

It would look something like this:

```
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyName)</a>
    </th>
```

Obviously you would replace *"Action"* with your action name and *"Controller"* with your controller name.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `Html.ActionLink`, and I assume your table header `CompanyName` is just rendered as `Company Name`.  If not, and you are displaying a different name.. then use zgood's answer.

```
<tr style="background: #d1d3d4">
    <th></th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Company Name", "Action", "Controller")
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vacancies.FirstOrDefault().VacancyName)
    </th>
```

Hope this helps.